# How can i apply the datatable filters to my php code?

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, datatable

I am getting some data and displaying on the table which i have created in my php code however i want to apply the data table filters but i cannot seem to find a solution. I know in html i can assign an id to the table and then call it from a js script using the following code   var table = `$('#myTable').DataTable({"dom":"ftip"});` however this doesn't seem to work in my code. Perhaps because i am wrapping the html code in `php?`

Thanks

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({"dom":"ftip"});

});

</script>

<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '""', 'calendar');

extract($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['readrecords'])){

    $data =  '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="myTable">
                        <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
                            <th>No.</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Driver</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>';

    $displayquery = "SELECT id,title, driver, start FROM `events` ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$displayquery);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        $number = 1;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $data .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$number.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['title'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['driver'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['start'].'</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>';
            $number++;

        }
    }
     $data .= '</table>';
        echo $data;

}

?>
```

function readRecords(){

```
    var readrecords = "readrecords";
    $.ajax({
        url:"backend.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{readrecords:readrecords},
        success:function(data,status){
            $('#records_content').html(data);
        },

    });
}
```

Comment: _“Perhaps because i am wrapping the html code in php?”_ - the browser (and that is where datatables runs, on the client side) doesn’t know anything about that, it only sees the end result. Whether your table was “static”, created by PHP, or maybe even typed and send over the net in real time by your grandma you locked into the server housing - absolutely irrelevant. Go check if the browser console has any JS errors, and compare the HTML code of your dynamically created table to the static, “working” version - likely there are some significant differences somewhere.